# Prefix in commandhandler

Tags: discord.js

When created in a command, this command is called every prefix. So suppose I have created a "help" command, then I can use everything as a prefix.

Examples:
!Help
?Help
.Help
-Help

How do I set that I have a fixed prefix.

(I use a command handler by the way)

Answer (score 1):

I don't get what you mean. Do you want to use `!, /, -,` etc.. prefixes for your help command ? Or do you want a one prefix like `!`?

## **Based on your answer you want this:**

1. Create a JSON file named config inside your projects

```
{
  "prefix": "YOUR PREFIX HERE"
}
```

2. In your main file do

```js
const { prefix } = require("./config.json");

bot.on('message', message => {

    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

})
```

Comment: I want one prefix. Now I can use everything as a prefix and I don't want that.I would like `!` as a prefix @txshiro

Comment: Thanks but I don't have my commands in the main file but in a commands folder. @txshiro

Comment: That doesn't matter. Just add ` if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;`  right under the message event and it will work

Comment: Thx!! You help me with this

Comment: No problem and don't forget to tag this answer as a solution for other people.